# Code in emacs .profile not running

Tags: java, gnu

I am trying to run the code

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This works whenever I type it into terminal, as shown by the command

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

However, this only persists throughout one instance of terminal. Whenever I try to run this in a new window, the command returns a blank space. 
I have tried adding this to my emacs .profile, but I get the same problem. The profile persists throughout the new windows, so it is being saved. How can I automatically run this code, if emacs .profile doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: emacs doesn't use `.profiile` it is typically read when a user logs in by a shell. You should read up on emacs init files

Comment: In Emacs, you can set env vars like `(setenv "JAVA_HOME" "/path/to/wherever")`.  It will be set in `term`, `shell`, and any other buffer.  Of course, if you set it in your shell's config (e.g. `~/.profile`) it will already be in Emacs's environment.